# load Dynamic libraries using rapth in mac

Tags: macos, dyld

I was going through the following article but I was not able to understand it completely.

[RunpathDependentLibraries](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/DynamicLibraries/100-Articles/RunpathDependentLibraries.html)

My situation is I have `A.dylib` which depends on `B.dylib`

```
A.dylib -> B.dylib
```

If I do  `System.loadLibrary(“A.dylib”)` and it’s failing even after keeping `B.dylib` into `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`

If I keep both `A.dylb` and `B.dylib` into the same directory it's working. But I do not need that.

Then I heard that I can modify my libraries to be path independent

But I do not understand it completely.  Can somebody provide some examples

Comment: Build Phase > Copy Files. Give the destination and add the lib/framework. It should work

Comment: @Anoop Could you please give the stepwise procedure

Comment: Select the target and do the above. Its straight forward.